Mosaics with very long names fail in GeoServer with Postgres
I am running GeoServer 2.24.4 with Postgres to host a series of image mosaics with long names. The problem is that it doesn’t seem to be honoring WrapStore=true in the indexer.properties for the mosaic. Is there a way to see the hidden mapping for the WrapStore to mapping to see if things are being mapped correctly? Multiple mosaics are being created with a data store but no layer. Is there something else that could cause this?
This is my indexer properties file:
AllowMultiThreading=true
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion),CRSExtractorSPI(crs)
AbsolutePath=false
WrapStore=true
USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD=false
Schema=*the_geom\:Polygon,location\:String,crs\:String,ingestion\:java.util.Date
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion

The mosaic I am adding is GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__Cloud_mixing_ratio77500Pa_Isobaric_surface_Mosaic (which is 68 characters long). When I look in postgres I can see the truncated name GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__Cloud_mixing_ratio77500Pa_Isobaric_surface_M.
EDIT:
When we try to delete a mosaic that is corrupted we see this in the logs:
2024-09-24 14:46:04,310 INFO  [org.geoserver.filters] (default task-2981) 10.42.7.0 "DELETE /geoserver/rest/workspaces/weather/coveragestores/GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__prodType_0_cat_19_subcat_21030000-1000Pa_Isobaric_surface_Mosaic/recurse=true&purge=all" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13.redhat-00001 (Java/1.8.0_412)" "" "text/xml"
2024-09-24 14:46:04,312 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-2981)
No mapping for DELETE
/geoserver/rest/workspaces/weather/coveragestores/GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__prodType_0_cat_19_subcat_21030000-1000Pa_Isobaric_surface_Mosaic/recurse=true&purge=all


what does the log say?

Postgresql limits the length of table names to 63 characters so your table name is being truncated and so GeoServer (and GeoTools) are unable to find it when they go to look it up with the longer name. This is a bug and you should open an issue to let the developers know, and if possible provide a fix. In the short term a workaround would be to use shorter layer names.

Isn't WrapStore supposed to fix this issue?
